# Error while moving Joomla from localhost to my website

Tags: joomla

I have Joomla installed on WAMP server, after configuring modules and plugins ....
I tried to move it to my website, I used the "Plesk file manager" to upload script
and then I successfully exported and imported database to remote host.
Beside database configuration, I reconfigured the `configuration.php` file as the following:

```
public $log_path = 'D:\\Inetpub\\vhosts\\site.com\\httpdocs\\site\\Joomla/logs';
public $tmp_path = 'D:\\Inetpub\\vhosts\\site.com\\httpdocs\\site\\Joomla/tmp';
```

but I got the following Error while browsing my joomla index page:

```
Warning: require_once(__DIR__/cache.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No error in D:\Inetpub\vhosts\site.com\httpdocs\site\Joomla\plugins\system\nnframework\helpers\protect.php on line 16

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '__DIR__/cache.php' (include_path='.;./includes;./pear') in D:\Inetpub\vhosts\site.com\httpdocs\site\Joomla\plugins\system\nnframework\helpers\protect.php on line 16
```

So how to repair this error?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually move the website, try to use a component such as [AkeebaBackup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-backup.html).

You can use the free version to make a backup, download it and then restore the website locally with the kickstart file.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.... seems like php version doesn't support `__DIR__` function
so I just replaced it with absolute directory location and that works fine